# What is the best translation for "toggle" in the context of options?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique

In English, the word "toggle" means to switch the state of something with two states. Turn on if off, and turn off if on. In programming, it could be written as `thing = !thing`.

What would be the best translation for a phrase like "Toggle Edit Mode"? A few ideas:

- Basculer mode édition
- Activer ou désactiver mode édition
- Changer mode édition
- Commuter mode édition
- Inversion mode édition

I got "basculer" from Google Translate, but it doesn't seem to be what I want, though I could be wrong. Alternative English translations include: tip, topple, tumble, overbalance.

I got "inversion" from Minecraft: `/toggledownfall` -> "Inversion des intempéries"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your suggestions are acceptable.

Depending on the available space, I would suggest :

> Activer / désactiver le mode édition
>
> *[Dés]activer mode édition*
>
> *[Commuter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commuter) mode édition*
>
> *Activer mode édition*
>
> *Mode édition*

*[Basculer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basculer)* is not a bad translation either. Here, it comes from *bascule* (seesaw):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some of your proposals are correct, but don’t seem natural to a native French speaker (in France).

Following other answer I’d propose

[Des] activer le mode édition

Commuter is not a commonly used word in French, looks like English, and won’t be understood...

If you have any way to speak to your developers, the best option would still be to have two strings 
Activer...
Désactiver...
Toggled from code
But that’s not often an option

Comment: The French and English *to commute* / *commuter* have moved away so much that they are mostly false friends nowadays. I agree the French *commuter* is not mainstream but it should be understood at least by technical aware people.

Comment: Commuter definitely doesn't sound like an English synonym for Toggle in any way.

Comment: Also, changing between Activer and Désactiver is not an option in some situations, such as when describing what a button does in a tutorial or in the settings menu.

Comment: good catch @AaronFranke