# Est-ce basculer « dans/en/sur/vers/à » (le) mode d'un programme : choix de préposition ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, verbes, informatique

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29630) on fait allusion au verbe [*basculer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basculer) en contexte du [*mode édition*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8382453), essentiellement un changement au mode opératoire d'un programme ; on a aussi des emplois techniques par extension pour une position et son contraire. On s'intéresse ici au choix de la préposition dans une phrase quand on utilise *basculer* dans le sens de *passer* (d'un mode à un autre) : est-ce [basculer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=basculer+dans%2Cbasculer+en%2Cbasculer+vers%2Cbasculer+sur%2Cbasculer+au%2Cbasculer+*_ADP+mode%2Cbasculer+mode&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20vers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20sur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20au%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasculer%20en_ADP%20mode%3B%2Cc0) *[dans](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dans/1)/[en](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)/[sur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur)/[vers](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vers/2)/[à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)* ce mode... ; on sait qu'on peut [*basculer vers une application*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8393186), qu'on a pu suggérer [*basculer sur off*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=BASCULER%20OFF&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour *toggle off* etc. Mais qu'en est-il pour le [*mode*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mode/1) comme type de fonctionnement dans ce domaine ?

---

- Pourquoi trouverait-on l'une ou l'autre préposition plus adéquate dans une phrase avec *basculer* et l'abstraction du *mode* en informatique ?
- Quelles nuances d'emploi de ces prépositions (*dans, en, sur, vers, à*), du verbe *basculer* ou du nom *mode* en informatique identifierait-on afin de nous guider dans ce choix ?

Comment: Il manque *basculer dans* qui est le plus courant !

Comment: @jlliagre Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Il ne semble pas qu'il y ait de consensus sur la préposition à utiliser ici.

Les cinq prépositions les plus courantes que trouvent les moteurs de recherche sont:

> - Basculer en mode xxx (à l'interieur du mode xxx)
> - Basculer vers le mode xxx (on bascule de A vers B)
> - Basculer dans le mode xxx (on bascule dans le vide)
> - Basculer sur le mode xxx (on bascule sur quelque chose qui est plus bas)
> - Basculer au mode xxx

Je suis assez surpris par *basculer au mode* dont la présence est peut-être due à de mauvaises traductions. *Au* ou *à* introduisent des directions, ce que peut difficilement être un mode. Je ne vois que *basculer à droite*, *basculer à gauche*, *basculer au nord*, etc.

Je n'ai pas d'opinion vraiment tranchée sur les trois premières expressions qui sont très similaires, sans vraiment de différence de sens.

Peut-être que ***basculer en mode xxx*** est le plus littéraire, c'est en tout cas le seul que trouve google books.

Comment: Merci ! _Basculer au_ me fait penser à _tourner/virer au_ + couleur, la précipitation disons. Sur quel prototype anglais penserais-tu qu'est construit _basculer au_ ?

Answer (score 1):

La bascule me semble indiquer une alternative, laquelle peut se définir soit par le passage d’un mode à un autre, sans limitation du nombre de modalités possibles ; ou alors par l’activation ou non d’un mode particulier.

On parle aujourd’hui couramment de [*mode, subst.masc.*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/mode) en désignant une certaine configuration d’esprit, liée ou non à une activité physique :

> Je revis Jacques souvent. Il me raconta son histoire avec Magda, **sur un mode romanesque**
>       *(Simone de Beauvoir in* Mémoires d'une jeune fille rangée)
>
> Mais il faut bien sortir de Mafate ; c'est à pied ou en hélico ! Et Françoise m'attend en haut. Bon, ben, j'y vais ; sans conviction. **En mode bête de somme.**
>       *([Le petit journal de l’Ardennes Mayotte Team](http://dcfcmaho.blogspot.ca/2014/10/n-89-objectif-grand-raid-de-la-reunion.html))*

L’image de la bascule ne semble cependant pas appropriée à ces deux exemples : le premier, introduit par *sur*, indique la manière ; le second, introduit par *en*, ne parle pas tant de l’enclanchement du mode bête de somme que de son statut actif. L’auteur eût-il d’ailleurs discuté de la transition qu’une tournure utilisant *activation* ou *enclanchement* m’eût semblé plus naturelle que celle de la bascule... Voire, en une parodie de science fiction à petit budget :

> Mode bête de somme activé.

L’idée de *bascule*, donc, me semble *a priori* mieux adaptée à un contexte informatique, où la transition se fait rapidement, parfois en un seul clic. Je tempère en supposant qu’un récit couvrant une grande période de temps, avec des transitions comparativement brèves entre différents états, pourrait jouer du concept de bascule.

> Cet été rempli d’expériences nouvelles touchait à sa fin. Déjà la toundra rougissait, le cycle des jours et des nuits, interrompu depuis quelques mois par ce soleil qui ne se couchait plus, reprenait son rhythme quotidien, et on pouvait pressentir qu’avant longtemps, la neige arriverait. Quant à elle, elle devrait bientôt retourner à l’université et **basculer en mode études**.

J’ai ici introduit le complément avec *en*, sans y réfléchir et en acceptant que le naturel s’imposerait. Pourrait-on y substituer *au, dans le, sur le* ou *vers le* ? Les trois premiers me semblent franchement disgracieux, quoique je ne puisse réellement mettre le doigt sur le bobo. Quant au dernier, *vers le*, eh bien, pourquoi pas ? Il ne fut pas mon choix naturel, et même en regardant la chose, je lui préfère encore *en*, mais tout est dans la manière de dire, et je suis convaincu que quelqu’un pourrait y insérer cette tournure avec élégance.

Concernant les utilisations informatiques, les utilisateurs sont habitués à la concision et aux courtes et denses expressions. J’en discute plus en longueur dans la section suivante.

---

Pour information concernant le mode actif, dans les applications, et donc en dehors du contexte de phrases prévu par la question :

Soit on passe d’un mode à un autre, transition pour laquelle j’accepterais sans broncher, ou seulement légèrement, différentes prépositions, avec de légères variations quant à l’utilisation d’un article, voire aucune préposition *(pour un style télégraphique sans doute non-orthodoxe, mais néanmoins tolérable à mon point de vue)* :

> basculer **en** mode écriture ↔ basculer **en** mode lecture
>   basculer **au** mode écriture ↔ basculer **au** mode lecture
>   basculer **vers le** mode écriture ↔ basculer **vers le** mode lecture
>   basculer mode écriture ↔ basculer mode lecture
>     basculer **dans le** mode écriture ↔ basculer **dans le** mode lecture
>     basculer **sur le** mode écriture ↔ basculer **sur le** mode lecture
>          <sup>(J’ai plus de difficulté avec les deux derniers, mais c’est peut-être strictement personnel)</sup>

Ou alors on parle d’un mode qui peut ou non être activé, auquel cas je préfère personnellement le couple de verbes ***activer—désactiver***. Si on désire coûte que coûte parler d’une bascule, alors les propositions ci-dessus (et leurs commentaires) demeureraient assez similaires. On notera les légères variantes sur le choix des verbes et des prépositions dans les miroirs.

> basculer **en** mode écriture ↔ quitter le mode écriture
>   basculer **au** mode écriture ↔ quitter le mode écriture
>   basculer **vers le** mode écriture ↔ basculer **hors le** mode écriture
>   basculer mode écriture ↔ basculer **hors** mode écriture
>     basculer **dans le** mode écriture ↔ basculer **hors du** mode écriture
>     basculer **sur le** mode écriture ↔ quitter le mode écriture
>          <sup>(De nouveau, j’ai plus de difficulté avec les deux derniers, mais encore, c’est peut-être moi le problème...)</sup>

Je remarque que mes préférences et mes réserves ne s’appliquent pas aux mêmes options que celles de [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29646/13100). Sans doute est-ce subjectif. Ce qu’il voit comme de mauvaises traductions *(au mode)* me semble naturel et fluide, et ce qui m’apparaît comme disgracieux *(dans le mode)* ne le fait guère broncher. Il semble qu’il existe sûrement différents points de vue défendables.

---

Pour des phrases dans un manuel quelconque ou un texte suivi de quelque nature que ce soit, ma préférence irait vraisemblablement à *en* dans la plupart des cas, ne serait-ce que parce que c’est ce qui s’est présenté à mon esprit quand je composais mon exemple cité plus haut. Je me dis que ce naturel, composé vraisemblablement d’une habitude linguistique faite d’écoutes, d’utilisations et de lectures, est sans doute celui aussi de bien des gens. Aucune raison particulière de lever le nez sur les autres options, seulement comme le pli est pris et que je ne vois pas de motifs raisonnables de remiser *en* pour cause de non-sens, barbarisme ou solécisme, je m’y tiens...

Comment: Merci ! Ce pourrait être les deux p.-ê. si l'alternative c'était entre un mode régulier et un mode spécifique, et qu'il y a plusieurs modes spécifiques, on peut croiser ça, mais je comprends la nuance des choix où l'action contraire s'exprime différemment, et c'est bien intéressant. Parfois on a même une interface qui montre des glissoirs et autres trucs du genre avec une étiquette et servant à activer une fonction, mais c'est plus ce qu'on emploierait dans une phrase complète dans un manuel pour décrire la transition etc. qui m'intéresse, c.-à-d. sans aucune contrainte et purement abstrait.

Comment: @Améraldor Je rumine et rumine depuis hier et ne sais comment rafistoler tout ça, ni vraiment par où commencer l’enquête. J'y travaille et y revient...

Comment: Merci encore là !